# ¿Porqué la función acabar_funciones se ejecuta más veces que de las que tiene agregado el controlador?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer 3 cosas:

1. Al poner debajo de un elemento(Hola, miren el ejemplo) se ejecute `mousesobre()`.
2. Que esta función añada dos controladores al elemento.
3. Una de estos controladores hace que se ejecute `al_moverse()` si se mueve o mientras de da clic con el mouse y la otra para cuando se deje de mover o de clicar se ejecute `acabar_funciones()` y que muestre una alerta y elimine `al_moverse()`.

**Problema:**

`acabar_funciones()` se ejecuta más de una vez y para solucionarlo eliminé el controlador que añadía `acabar_funciones()` al `window` en esta función para que cuando se ejecute `al_moverse()` no se ejecute más de una vez. Pero no funciona, ¿Por qué?, adjunto mi código:

```js
document.getElementById("ej").addEventListener("mousedown", mousesobre);
function mousesobre() {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", al_moverse);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () { acabar_funciones(al_moverse) });
  function al_moverse() {
    console.log("Hola");//Ignoren si quieren esta linea, no afecta con nada al código, solo la he puesto porque tengo código aca
  }
  function acabar_funciones(funcion) {
    alert("NO");
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", funcion);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', function () { acabar_funciones(al_moverse) });
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="ej">Hola</p>
```

El `alert()` lo he puesto solo para comprobar las veces que `acabar_funcion()` se ejecuta, y solo debe ejecutarse una vez.

Pienso que hace eso porque se le añade más de una vez el evento `mouseup` al `"Hola"`, por eso he tratado de eliminarlo pero aún así sigue sin funcionar, no entiendo porque se ejecuta más de una vez el `alert()`.

¿Podrían explicármelo?.

Comment: Sí, es por eso. Sería bueno que expliques lo que estás intentando hacer para ayudarte a ordenar el código.

Comment: Como dice @Lobos agrega a tu pregunta qué estás intentando lograr para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes ir leyendo sobre [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Cuando el mouse este bajo el Hola quiero que ejecute efe, si se mueve se ejecute algo() y cuando se deje de pulsar el mouse o se finalice el click el f(). Lo que pasa es que he visto que f() se ejecuta más de una vez, pensé que era porque se ha añadido más de una vez la f() al window. Así que eliminé el controlador de eventos que lo llamaba, pero no funcionó, algo sigue llamando al f() y no se que es.

Comment: Para aclarar más quiero que cuando se deje de clickar o se deje de pulsar el mouse se ejecute f() 1 sola vez. Para que no se le añadan más de un controlador de eventos cuando se vuelva a ejecutar efe, pensé en removerlo, pero no funcionó. ¿Porqué?

Comment: Se entiende un poco más, pero ¿Cuál es el objetivo final de todo esto?

Comment: Igual hay otra cosa que llama a f() pero no se cual es, lo he revisado y no entiendo. La única cosa que llama a f() es window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){f(algo)}); pero lo elimino cada vez después de ejecutarlo para que no se ejecute más de 1 vez, pero no.

Comment: Resumiendo que el objetivo final es que quiero que f() se ejecute un vez cuando se clicke o se deje de mantener pulsado. Pero conservando la estrucutra que tiene la función efe().

Comment: Estoy intentando aun comprender aca con el codigo pero quería decirte que también intentes siempre ponerle nombres más descriptivos a las funciones por más pequeño que parezca el código.

Comment: Espero que ahora se entienda 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que es un lio jugar agregando y sacando eventos, es más fácil colorcar una variable para `pressed` para saber si el botón del mouse está presionado o no

```js
let pressed=false;
document.getElementById("ej").addEventListener("mousedown", () => pressed=true);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", () =>{
 if(pressed)
 {
     console.log("move")
 }
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => pressed=false);
```

```html
<p id="ej">Hola</p>
```

Ahora si tu realmente quieres usar `removeEventListener` puede ser algo como esto:

```js
const mousemove = () => console.log("move");
const mouseup = () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove",mousemove);

document.getElementById("ej").addEventListener("mousedown", () => window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove));

window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
```

```html
<p id="ej">Hola</p>
```

Si te fijas en ambos casos la "solución" pasa por desanidar la funciones que tú tienes, es lo que genera un enredo que es difícil de entender y de depurar.